# Is it possible for another user to insert in the middle of a multi-value insert?

Tags: insert, mariadb

Is it possible for another user to insert in the middle of a multi-value insert?
By multi-value insert I mean:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/#multi-value-inserts
The reason I am asking is to make sure the auto-increment values for the multi-value insert are serial and another insert cannot insert some value in the middle them.

Comment: Please show details.  And include the settings for `tx_isolation` and `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` and `sql_mode`.

Comment: @RickJames, "sql_mode: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"; "tx_isolation: REPEATABLE-READ"; "innodb_autoinc_lock_mode: 1". By the way what do you think about what I quoted from MariaDB's documentation as an answer?

Comment: That batch insert often runs 10 times as fast when inserting 100 row at a time (versus 100 single-row `INSERTs`).  So, yes, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

> and another insert cannot insert some value in the middle them

There's no table locking involved so you cannot assume this.

> The reason I am asking is to make sure the auto-increment values for the multi-value insert are serial

What for? They just need to be unique which is taken care by the database. If you rely on the order of values then it looks like your architecture/design is wrong at some point.

Comment: I need the values in order to insert them into another table. To achieve that  I use "result.insertId" and increment it for each row.

Comment: then you cannot use multi-value insert or use it in other db, do your work, then dump that db and import as is. autoincrement will not be generated if you provide the value (yet it must not exists or import will fail)

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/auto_increment-handling-in-xtradbinnodb/
for XtraDB and InnoDB storage engines:

> The innodb_autoinc_lock_mode server system variable determines the lock mode for auto-increments.

and

> ### Consecutive Lock Mode
>
> Set by innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=1, the consecutive lock mode holds a table-level lock for all bulk INSERTs (such as LOAD DATA or INSERT ... SELECT) until the end of the statement. For simple INSERTs, no table-level lock is held. Instead, a lightweight mutex is used which scales significantly better. This is the default setting.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?  It is saying that another connection cannot get an id in the middle of your batch insert.

Comment: @RickJames, I guess it does, but as it mentions that a mutex is used instead of a table level lock I still have a little doubt about the serial auto-increment guarantee.

Comment: @RickJames, Am I doubtful more than needed?

Comment: A mutex will block all other connections from doing a particular thing.  The choice to use a mutex instead of a table-level-lock was probably an implementation detail.  The effect should be the same (at the level we are discussing).

Comment: This may also be useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html. I'm not sure how much different or similar it is for various versions of mariaDB though. For that version of mysql it says that a mutex is only held for the duration of the allocation process,  not until the statement completes.

Comment: AFAIK, MariaDB is identical to MySQL in that (and many other) area.  Note "duration of allocation process" -- this should be a very short (microseconds?) process, hence suitable for a "mutex".  "Completing the statement" could talk many seconds, due to I/O, etc.

Comment: So, the mutex is, in some sense, "a table level lock", in that it allows only one alloc can be happening at a time.  However, "table level lock" _normally_ refers to blocking bigger things such as alters/inserts/selects/etc.